# Nested table-row not not filling 100% in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I'm working with quite a complex layout using display: table-row and in IE I can't get the row to stretch when I'm using a nested table.

Check out this in http://jsfiddle.net/DVxpZ/7/ in Chrome/FF vs IE(10)

I want the blue row to stretch to fill the available space and the purple row to be at the bottom.

Any advice gratefully received. I tried using position: fixed; for this kind of layout but then I can't get the rows to resize as the screen size gets smaller.

```
<div id="full-height" class="table">
    <header class="table-row"><div class="button"></div></header>
    <div id="main"class="table-row">
        <div class="table">
            <div id="row1" class="table-row"><div class="button"></div></div> 
            <div id="row2" class="table-row"><div class="button"></div></div> 
            <div id="row3" class="table-row"><div class="button"></div></div> 
            <div id="row4" class="table-row stretch-row"><div class="button"></div></div> 
            <div id="row5" class="table-row"><div class="button"></div></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
}
.full-cell{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main{
    height: 100%;
}

.button{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 3px;
}

#row1{
    background-color: pink;
}

#row2{
    background-color: orange;
}

#row3{
    background-color: red;
}

#row4{
    background-color: blue;
}


#row5{
    background-color: purple;
}


#full-height{ 
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stretch-row{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Try to reset all element margin??

http://jsfiddle.net/DVxpZ/9/